Odoo v15 Qweb Report Date_Format and configuration Adding more spaces (%m - %d - %Y)

i tried
context_timestamp(datetime.datetime.(page['date'].)).strftime('%m - %d - %Y')
but the maximum space is only 1 it will not fit on the bank check format which needs 2 spaces between numbers("date") on Account Qweb report Print check (Top)
Please help I want to put more (atleast 2)spaces between numbers(date) so that it fits on BDO bankcheck date_format

It's solve the problem using this code
 '  '.join('  '.join(o.date.strftime('%m%d%Y')).split())

I just answered it so that if someone has the same problem, they will see this :)
